# Puppeteer in Gitlab CI/CD, testing in Headfull browser not working

Tags: docker, gitlab, puppeteer, gitlab-ci

I have a puppeteer project for testing my main application, that has some features that relies on visiblity, so have to be tested in headful mode.

I wanted to be able to start the testing script from gitlab (so that i can chain the pipeline to the main app), but seems that i cannot force the headless property to true: in fact, when I run the same script with `healess: true`, it works, while it fails for `headless: false`.

The error is:

```
> jest --runInBand
 Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
 Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
 [1485:1485:0908/113752.573573:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.
 TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
     at onClose (/builds/tests-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/builds/tests-puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:740:61)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:326:22)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
```

my `jest-puppeteerconfig` file:

```
module.exports = {
  launch: {
      headless: false,
      slowMo: process.env.SLOWMO ? process.env.SLOWMO : 0,
      devtools: false,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, 
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--window-size=1920,1040']
  }
}
```

And my `.gitlab-CI.yaml`:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

Integration_Tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
    - npm install
    - npm test
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: it is something cannot be solved purely in puppeteer. in case of GitHub Actions there are some dedicated actions, e.g.: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/puppeteer-headful, with GitLab I am not aware of any. if you are OK with `puppeteer-extra` npm package: you could try its *stealth plugin* which makes the headless chrome act like headful chrome https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth but honestly I am not sure if it helps in your use case.

Comment: I was not aware of this plugin, i will give it a try! regarding the difference between GitLab and GitHub i already found something in other questions here and around the net, but unfortunately i cannot change host

Comment: yeah, I suppose it is not the reason to change to GitHub. I am not sure if stealth will solve your issue. but you can take a look into the docker file of the GitHub Action solution, maybe it helps you to re-create it for GitLab https://github.com/mujo-code/puppeteer-headful/blob/master/Dockerfile ... meantime I hope there will be more helpful comments/answers.